Meaning of 痺れを切らした in this context
Here is a scene from She is Beautiful chapter 42:

Let me write a brief summary of what happened so far in the story. 清香 and くるみ ran away from the place 箱庭. Two agents 岬 and 葵 from 箱庭 was dispatched to hunt them down to kill them. At some point, 清香 and くるみ got separated from each other. 清香 was trying to get くるみ back to her side. For some reason, 岬 and 葵 changed their mind and decided to capture くるみ and send her back to 箱庭. The above panel shows 岬 predicting 清香's motives.
There's one sentence I am unsure:

清香がくるみに接触しなければ痺れを切らした私たちはいずれくるみを箱庭に送還する

I am not sure about the meaning of 痺れを切らした and who is doing it. Due to absence of punctuation in manga, it is hard to make sense of this sentence. There are two ways I can interpret it:

清香がくるみに接触しなければ痺れを切らした。私たちはいずれくるみを箱庭に送還する。

清香がくるみに接触しなければ、痺れを切らした私たちはいずれくるみを箱庭に送還する。


I suspect 2 is most likely interpretation. In that case 痺れを切らした means to be tired or to be  impatient?

Please post a higher resolution image next time :)

@naruto Actually, the original image link is https://i.sstatic.net/p4FcOcfg.png. I thought it looked too big for the post, so to make it smaller, I added the suffix 'm' to the end of the identification code like this: https://i.sstatic.net/p4FcOcfgm.png.

It's the latter.

We will eventually lose patience and send Kurumi back to Familie. ...And that was probably the aim of Sayaka.

痺れを切らす means "to be tired of waiting", not "to be tired".
If I understand the context correctly, Misaki, Aoi, and Sayaka all understand that Kurumi is used to lure out Sayaka.
